# 404 Monitoring Tool for nginx

Tags: logging, nginx, http-status-code-404, monitoring

I'm looking for a nice tool or log parser to monitor my site for **404** activity at the server level in **nginx**.

*Edit 2: I did not have enough info.  This is an app being served by uWSGI, which means that it's never really a "true" error to nginx - a page is being served successfully.*

*So If I want to keep my custom 404 page, I'll need to have that uWSGI's app's code do it.*

I could always `grep 404 mysite.access.log` but that's pretty weak.  There's got to be some better tools out there, and I'm not finding them.

One suggestion in IRC has been to output Apache-style logs, and then use tools available for Apache, such as `apachetop`.  Is this the way to go?

*Edit: Another tool could be `wtop` here https://code.google.com/p/wtop/*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are after, do you want to see it in realtime any 404 or do you want to get it into som monitoring solution like nagios?

If you want to see it realtime in a shell and have moderate to low traffic the wtop etc. would certainly work for you. If you have high volume traffic, parsing logs in realtime can be really really slow and hog a lot of resources.

In that case I personally would use a special @location for it with its own logging to send it to a special logfile. Or, have a 404 redirect to a script of some kind, that just add to a counter that you can read with your cacti or nagios monitoring to get both graphs and/or alerts.

This does what you want, and you can have different counters for different errors to make it really pretty.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_intercept_errors

Comment: Thanks!  Here's my latest issue:

I turned on `proxy_intercept_errors` (actually `uwsgi_intercept_errors`)

Now, I have a location @404 that is working and logging to a separate file.  nginx is doing its job.

The problem is that this is unworkable, because I no longer get my custom 404 page from the App being served by uWSGI.

So, I think the full solution is to continue allowing my uWSGI-based app to serve the custom 404 page, which is then not an "error" to nginx at all.  I can have that custom 404 page do the logging to a separate file.

Comment: Sounds like a plan to do the logging inside the app then. Esp. if you want to catch all with your app, then it is technically not a 404 to the server in that sense.